# I want to add a column named serial number and fill in that column till n where n is number of count of items in the adjacent column

Tags: vba

PFB, I have shown the raw data which we get from the tool and the required format.

The number of rows will be dynamic everyday.

```
Raw Data                            Required Data

Item       Rank           Sr. No.  Item  Rank Rank Rank
 a     210450  (-1%)         1       a    210  450  (-1%)
 b     230500  (5%)          2       b    230  500  (5%)
```

Answer (score 0):

Enter the number 1 where you want the serial number to be 1. In this example that cell is presumed to be D4. Enter the formula below in the cell below the 1 (here D5) and copy down as far as you want or need.

```
[D5] =D4+1
```

You can use the same formula to start numbering from any number other than 1. All you need to do is to change the first number manually, leaving the formula in place.

Another method is to use the formula below.

```
[D4] = ROW()-3
```

Here 3 is the row number above the cell of the first entry. The same formula works in call columns. Copy down as far as needed

Comment: Hi Variatus, The number of rows will be dynamic everyday. I needed a vba code for the same. I have shown the raw data and the required output.

Comment: At this site we help you do things. We don't do them for you. Just knowing what you want isn't considered an "own effort" here.